# ASP.NET Core Web API with ReturnHttpNotAcceptable and custom media types results in "no output formatter found" on 4xx responses

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, media-type

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API (TargetFramework is `net5.0`) where I accept 2 media types:

- `application/json`
- `application/vnd.my.customtype+json`

I have a basic controller as follows:

```cs
[ApiController]
[ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
[Route("")]
public class RootController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpHead]
    [Route("", Name = "get_root")]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get))]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return this.Ok(new { Item1 = "item 1" });
    }
}
```

If I make a `GET` request with the header `Accept: application/json` and return a `200 OK` with a result, everything is fine:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:5001

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 18

{"item1":"item 1"}
```

If I make a `GET` request with the header `Accept: application/vnd.my.customtype+json` and return a `200 OK` with a result, everything is also fine:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.my.customtype+json
Host: localhost:5001

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.my.customtype+json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 18

{"item1":"item 1"}
```

The same controller returning a 404 (e.g. if a resource is not found)

```cs
[ApiController]
[ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
[Route("")]
public class RootController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpHead]
    [Route("", Name = "get_root")]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get))]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return this.NotFound();
    }
}
```

Now, if I make a `GET` request with the header `Accept: application/json`, everything is fine (I get a proper 404 as well as ProblemDetails in the response body):

```
GET https://localhost:5001/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:5001

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 161

{
  "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
  "title":"Not Found",
  "status":404,
  "traceId":"00-54d50dfe6a27674ba83a73324fcf2721-d4286734f860c94a-00"
}
```

If I make a `GET` request with the header `Accept: vnd.my.customtype+json`, I get a `406 Not Acceptable` response:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.my.customtype+json
Host: localhost:5001

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
```

And in the logs, I get this:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/ - -

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'Hooli.WebAPI.Controllers.RootController.Get (Hooli.WebAPI)'

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Root"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Get() on controller Hooli.WebAPI.Controllers.RootController (Hooli.WebAPI).

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      No output formatter was found for content types 'application/problem+json, application/problem+xml' to write the response.

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Hooli.WebAPI.Controllers.RootController.Get (Hooli.WebAPI) in 0.8058ms

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'Hooli.WebAPI.Controllers.RootController.Get (Hooli.WebAPI)'

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/ - - - 406 0 - 1.1703ms
```

Note the `warn` line: `No output formatter was found for content types 'application/problem+json, application/problem+xml' to write the response.`

I cannot figure out why this will not return a proper `404` with problem details.

My Startup.cs is as follows:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(
                     options =>
                     {
                         options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
                     })
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(
                     options =>
                     {
                         options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                             new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
                             {
                                 NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(true, true)
                             };
                     });

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(
            options =>
            {
                NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter =
                    options.OutputFormatters.OfType<NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault() ??
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter));

                // add media types that we want to support by default
                newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter
                    .SupportedMediaTypes
                    .Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.my.customtype+json"));
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(env.IsDevelopment() ? "/error-local-development" : "/error");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
```

And just for completeness, my Program.cs file:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
}
```

I have stripped my API down to this most basic setup to rule out any additional middleware / configurations. It doesn't matter what status code I return, if it is any of the `4xx` responses I always get a `406` when the `Accept` header is the custom media type.

e.g.

- this.BadRequest();
- this.NotFound();
- this.Unauthorized();
- etc.

If I change `options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true` to `options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = false`, the responses come back fine for everything, but then the API doesn't return a 406 when an invalid media type is passed in the `Accept` header.

How can I get the API to return the proper response when the custom media type is in the `Accept` header?

Comment: you need to implement your own custom `IOutputFormatter` and configure your mvc middleware to use it, take a look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-5.0 The custom media type here is `application/problem+json`

Comment: @KingKing, is there any way that I can tell `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` to handle it? Ultimately, the output is going to be the same as `application/json`, which the `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` already handles.

Comment: I'm not so sure, you can however have a very simple implementation of `IOutputFormatter` because it uses the `System.Text.Json` or some other JSON lib. I don't know why you want such a custom media type (but in fact just an alias name for the standard type`application/json`), what if you try changing the `Accept` header value to `application/json` as soon as possible on the server side? Maybe the output processing will take the latest header value in consideration.

Comment: I see you have this `newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes` in your code, have you tried adding the media type `application/problem+json` to there? What is the value for `CustomMediaTypeNames.Global.HateoasJson`? as that's already added.

Comment: @KingKing, sorry, that was a copy/paste leftover; I have updated that code. The actual value there is
`newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.my.customtype+json"));`

I have added
`newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/problem+json"));` 
as well, but I still get the 406 (as above)

Comment: so you just add the media type `application/vnd.my.customtype+json`, you need to add the `application/problem+json` as well. It should work.

Comment: @KingKing - see previous comment... I hit enter too quickly. But I add that yet still get the same 406.

Comment: sorry that I do not have .NET 5 environment to test it out. But I've tested it with .NET Core 2.2 and see this: In the `Configure<MvcOptions>`, `OutputFormatters` is empty but in the `AddMvc(o => ...)` the `OutputFormatters` are populated with 4 default ones. One of them is `JsonOutputFormatter` with a supported media type like this `application/*+json` (looks like it supports wildcard as well). So you should try moving the code to `AddMvc` and see if it works. Also try debugging as well, if the wildcard `application/*+json` is included by default you may not need to add yours which match it.

Comment: You don't actually tell MVC that the action returns your custom media-type. It doesn't know how to return a problem-details as `application/vnd.my.customtype+json`, so it has no choice but to return a 406. You can prove that by adding `[Produces("application/vnd.my.customtype+json")]` to either the controller or the action in question. Or you can state that you will also accept `application/json`, e.g. `Accept: application/vnd.my.customtype+json;applicaton/json` in the request.

Comment: Both methods have the default media types (including application/*+json) and then after I add mine, it contains that one too.

If I leave the custom one out, it always returns 406 - no matter what

Comment: @KirkLarkin, thank you for that info. I see what you're saying now. So, my question would be now - how do I "teach" mvc how to return problem details as `application/vnd.my.customtype+json`?  Is that where I would need to build a custom output formatter? Since technically `application/vnd.my.customtype+json` is just JSON, I would prefer that the `newtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` simply handle that for me. Is there any way to tell THAT formatter to handle processing for `application/vnd.my.customtype+json` ?

Comment: `ProducesAttribute` is good for API explorer (e.g: using SwaggerUI) and it forces the output to return that type but I don't think it's required in this case when the client request has the header `Accept`. That header will be read and processed accordingly. The issue is somehow `IOutputFormatter` for that type is not found, really strange. Again do debug carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a class:

```
public class CustomOutputFormatter: OutputFormatter
    {
        public CustomOutputFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.my.customtype+json"));
        }
        
        public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(context.Object);
        }
    }
```

And register in your services:

```
services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
    })
    .AddMvcOptions(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomOutputFormatter()))
```

Comment: That works for successful responses, but when any 4xx response occurs, it still comes back as a 406.

`warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]`
`No output formatter was found for content types 'application/problem+json, application/problem+xml' to write the response.`

Comment: not sure what's the issue. I had a typo in ````SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("vnd.my.customtype+json"));````, which should be ````application/vnd.my.customtype+json````, have you correct this part? Can you post your new ````ConfigureServices()```` method?

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a expected behavior of the system. The problem is that when an exception occurred that resulted in 4xx response and the response content type would be changed to `application/problem+json`.

If there was no Accept header and the content type supposed to be returned is application/json, then application/problem+json is a subset of application/json. So it would work.

If the request had Accept header like `Accept: application/vnd.my.customtype+json`, then `application/problem+json` is not a subset of `application/vnd.my.customtype+json`. So it would not work. Hence the behavior.

So one possible solution is to override OutputFormatterSelector and choose the correct formatter,

```cs
public class AcceptHeaderOutputFormatterSelector : OutputFormatterSelector
    {
        private readonly DefaultOutputFormatterSelector _fallbackSelector;
        private readonly List<IOutputFormatter> _formatters;

        public AcceptHeaderOutputFormatterSelector(IOptions<MvcOptions> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _fallbackSelector = new DefaultOutputFormatterSelector(options, loggerFactory);
            _formatters = new List<IOutputFormatter>(options.Value.OutputFormatters);
        }

        public override IOutputFormatter? SelectFormatter(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context, IList<IOutputFormatter> formatters, MediaTypeCollection mediaTypes)
        {

            var selectedFormatter = _fallbackSelector.SelectFormatter(context, formatters, mediaTypes);
            if (selectedFormatter == null)
            {
                var isAProblemDetailsType = mediaTypes.Any(i => i.Contains("problem+"));
                if (isAProblemDetailsType)
                {
                    var acceptableMediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.ParseList(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Accept).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (acceptableMediaType == null)
                    {
                        return selectedFormatter;
                    }

                    string acceptableMediaTypeStr = $"{acceptableMediaType.Type}/{acceptableMediaType.Suffix}";
                    
                    selectedFormatter = _formatters.FirstOrDefault(i =>
                    {
                        OutputFormatterCanWriteContext formatterContext = context;
                        formatterContext.ContentType = acceptableMediaTypeStr;
                        formatterContext.ContentTypeIsServerDefined = false;
                        return i.CanWriteResult(formatterContext);
                    });

                }
            }

            return selectedFormatter;
        }
    }
```

then in your program.cs or starup.cs, add the following to override the default output formatter selector,

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<OutputFormatterSelector, AcceptHeaderOutputFormatterSelector>();
```